# String replacement using gsub or sub

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I am studying for an exam tomorrow. One of the previous questions was to define a method to add a `e` to an array element (array of symbols) if the element ended with `a` or add an `s` if it ended with `i`.

Without using gsub or sub I can do this fine:

```
arbitrary = [:alpha, :beta, :kappa, :phi]
p arbitrary

def pluralise (array)
  manipulate = []
  array.each {|member|
    string = member.to_s
    last_char = string[-1,1]
    if last_char == "a" then
      string = string + "e"
      manipulate << string.to_sym
    end
    if last_char == "i" then
      string = string + "s"
      manipulate << string.to_sym
    end

  }
  manipulate

end

new_arbitrary = pluralise(arbitrary)

p new_arbitrary
```

However, attempting this with `gsub` or `sub` does not change the array:

```
arbitrary = [:alpha, :beta, :kappa, :phi]
p arbitrary

def pluralisesub (array)
  manipulate = []
  array.each {|member|
    string = member.to_s    
    last_char = string[-1,1]
    if last_char == "a" then
      string.gsub(string, string + "s")
      manipulate << string.to_sym
    end
    if last_char == "i" then
      string.gsub(string,string + "s")
      manipulate << string.to_sym
    end

  }
  manipulate

end

new_arbitrary = pluralisesub(arbitrary)

p new_arbitrary
```

Does anybody have any ideas what is going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the line `string.gsub(string, string + "s")` to `string.gsub!(string, string + "s")`. It will work.

[`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) works on the copy of the receiver, where as [`String.gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) works on the receiver itself.

Comment: Great - this works! Will accept (must wait 12 mins according to stack overflow)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the entire find and replace on in array in a map and case statement.

```
[:alpha, :beta, :kappa, :phi].map do |v|
  v = v.to_s
  case v[-1]
  when 'a' then v + 'e'
  when 'i' then v + 's'
  else v
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I had thought about using `map`. However the exam question is specific in that we must use `each` , `collect` or `select` :)

Comment: Well that's just stupid. You should also use `do`/`end` instead of braces.

Comment: `map`is an alias of `collect`.